# weird output when trying to format a string with moment.js and calculating time difference

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm passing a string representing a 24 hour datetime like HH:mm, I'm trying to format it in order to compare and get remaining time between two datetimes, however I'm getting a very weird output and my function is returning NaN when outputting time difference..

```js
const remainingHourAndMinute = (endDate) => {
  var now = moment().format('HH:mm');
  console.log('now', now);
  var end = moment(endDate, 'HH:mm'); //Here I format the string to a moment object
  console.log('end', end);
  var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(now));

  //Get Days and subtract from duration
  var days = duration.asDays();
  duration.subtract(moment.duration(days, 'days'));

  //Get hours and subtract from duration
  var hours = duration.hours();
  duration.subtract(moment.duration(hours, 'hours'));

  //Get Minutes and subtract from duration
  var minutes = duration.minutes();
  duration.subtract(moment.duration(minutes, 'minutes'));

  //Get seconds
  var seconds = duration.seconds();

  return hours > 0 ? hours + ' horas y ' + minutes + ' minutos' : minutes + ' minutos';
};

let closingTime = '21:00';
let remaining = remainingHourAndMinute(closingTime);
console.log(remaining);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

This is what the console logs.

```
now 18:56
end "2020-12-09T20:00:00.000Z"
diff NaN minutes
```

Notice how the now time is a normal 24h datetime but end is such a weird parsed format, that's why I think my function is giving me NaN, because I'm comparing dattimes in different formats...

Comment: subtract just takes a numeric value and a subject, no idea why you are doing `moment.duration()`. i've actually never seen that before. try just calling subtract directly like `duration.subtract(days,'days')` etc.

Comment: I believe passing a format to moment() just tells it what the values you are giving represent, and it still creates a full datetime object. You would need to console.log end.format("HH:mm") to see something that looks like now

Comment: `moment().format('HH:mm');` returns a string. Just make it a moment object, like `let now = moment();` Then you'll get reasonable values. They may be negative, depending on the time of day, of course.